# Sort a list with duplicate items by the number of duplicate occurrences

Tags: python, list

I have

```
list1 = ["one", "two", "two", "three", "five", "five", "five", "six"]
```

and the output should be

```
list2 = ["five" , "two", "one", "three" , "six"]
```

- `"five"` is the first element because in list1 has the highest number of occurrences (3)
- `"two`" is the second element because in list1 has the next highest number of occurrences (2)
- `"one"`, `"three`" and `"six"` have the same lower number of occurrences (1) so they are last in my `list2` - it doesn't really matter what order as long as they are after "five" and "two". `list2 = ["five" , "two", "six", "three", "one"]` or `list2 = ["five" , "two", "three", "one", "six"]` or any other variations are acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension and [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter
print([element for element,count in Counter(list1).most_common()])
```

Outputs:

```
['five', 'two', 'three', 'six', 'four', 'one']
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. @donkey-kong Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get a list sorted by the number of occurrences:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = [(uniq, len(list(dups)))
           for uniq, dups in groupby(sorted(list1))]  # group & count
grouped.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)  # sort by occurrence
list2 = list(map(itemgetter(0), grouped))
```

If duplicates are already grouped in `list1` (like in your question) then you can drop the `sorted()` call. `groupby()` may be more efficient (memory/time -wise) than `collections.Counter()` -- measure it if it is important in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Use a counter collection That is its specific purpose

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score -2):

```
a= ["one", "two", "two", "three", "four" , "five", "five", "five", "six"]
dic={}
for name in a:
    if name in dic:
        dic[name]=dic[name]+1
    else:
        dic[name]=1

keyList=[]
valueList=dic.values()
valueList.sort()
valueList.reverse()

def get_Value(dic,value):
    for name in dic:
        if dic[name] == value:
            del dic[name]
            return name


for num in valueList:
    keyList.append(get_Value(dic,num))  

print keyList
```